# What is best approach to creating a persistant UIView nav bar in a UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I've added a custom UIView to my base UITabBarController. I start by hiding the default tabBar. The viewdidload looks like this in UITabBarController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //hide default tab bar
    self.tabBar.isHidden = true


    tabBarArea.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width        
    tabBarArea.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height - tabBarArea.frame.height
    self.view.addSubview(tabBarArea)
}
```

That works well. The tabBarArea is defined in the storyboard as a custom view for the UITabBarController. The custom view sits between the First Responder and the Exit icons in the top bar.

Now, the problem is that the UITabBarController will disappear as soon as we load a child view controller and this custom UIView area will vanish with it.

Is there a way to make this root custom view always present even when child view controllers are loaded in?

Thanks for input. I like the idea of this custom UIView area but this approach needs refinement. I also don't need it to be a traditional UITabBarController with tab bar items, etc. I'd like to break out of that mold and just have custom UIButtons are whatever in this view area.

Comment: that child VC is added as a child to the tabBarController or it's a view Controller loaded with id to be pushed

Comment: Move the view of the tabBarArea above the view of the child VC

Comment: ah, i was using a segue to push the child vc. if i just add it as a child instead it should work right?